# Rails 4 Assets are not compiling in production environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts, asset-pipeline

My app is running in dev environment. I am using JQCloud.
Its working fine in development mode but when i run following command

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

All assets precompile but after running my server in production mode i am getting following error.

```
jQCloud is not a function


application.css.scss

 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome
 */


appication.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

dashing widegts index.js

```
//= require_tree .
//= require highcharts/highstock
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require highcharts/modules/exporting
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jqcloud
```

Facing error following errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jQCloud is not a function 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
```